# Buttons are not clickable after scrolling iframe in iOS (Mobile Safari)

Tags: ios, iframe, scroll, safari, webkit

Elements inside an iframe are unable to be taped after the iframe is scrolled using window.scrollTo() or window.scrollBy()

Reproduction steps:

1. Visit https://victornpb.github.io/ios-scrollable-iframe-issue/
2. Click the buttons on the left, it changes color to show that it is working.
3. Click the "Scroll down" button and it scrolls the iframe down by 50 pixels.
4. After that the buttons doesn't work at all.

[image: Screen capture of the issue]
[Screen capture video](https://bug-197613-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=369123)

It works fine on Desktop Safari, this issue only happens on Mobile Safari

I opened an issue on webkit repo [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197613) just in case.

iPhone `iOS 12.1 (16B92)`

I need to work around this limitation/bug, I can't add external scrolling though, because I need scroll events inside the iframe.